# `Unable to dequeue a cell with identifier MyCell`

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I have a TableViewController and static cells inside it; and I am trying to give one of the cells a class and detect it with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. I use..

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But when I use this it crashes

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell
}
```

> `unable to dequeue a cell with identifier MyCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: in `viewDidLoad`, did you do `tableView.registerClass(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")`? By the way, did you create a nib file for your custom cell? If you did, you might need to call `tableView.registerNib(nib:forCellReuseIdentifier:)` instead.

Comment: It's on the Main.StoryBoard. I didn't create a separate nib file. I tried adding your code on my viewDidLoad. Now it crashes on the same line but takes a bit more (2 more seconds loading) and then crash.. :/ What may be the problem?

Comment: You use static tableView, you don't have to dequeue static table view cells. just make a Outlet to your viewController and that's it

Comment: Ahh.. But then, how would I be able to use in `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` to make it stretchable? I placed `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80;
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` these two on viewDidLoad, and I was planning to make a check in there. Would it work that way if I make IBOutlet connection and call it in `let cell = outletVariable` in `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @senty you can still identify the IBOutlet cell through an index path if that is what you are wondering. That way you can still use the `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to deque cell in

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

}
```

Never deque cells outside of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

If you want an instance of the cell, you can just use

```
tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

This'll solve the problem.

Comment: So should I only write `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)` in `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`? I didn't understand what to do. Is the problem with connecting it with outlet? I couldn't make the check inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, that's why I tried this approach..

Comment: Yes. ```deque``` is used when the cell is being created or reused. If you want a reference of the cell, just call the above method.

Comment: Ah, so for the sake of clarification, for static cells I shouldn't use `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, only for dynamic cells.. I used @IBOutlet approach instead